# How to get notified when a new user signed up with our app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Can anyone tell me how can I get notifications with their mail Id and name on my app when a new user signed up with my app?

For example I am the developer of an app on which users will sign up, and I will make an app for myself to get notified when and how many users signed up with my production app I am using Firebase for authentication, can anyone give me some ideas on this?

Comment: Just make a simple http request to your server once in a few to check if users table has increased in rows. If so, you can return the total users now and notify yourself.

Comment: You need to write a simple php script which you can hit when the user is signed up successfully. When the script is called, it will launch a notification to your admin app. The php script is very simple and you can find one on the internet. Use Firebase notifications for this purpose.

Comment: Look into Cloud Functions for Firebase.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: I want notification and their information like mail Id score name should be saved in my admin app

Comment: I'll try all of these suggestions, thanks

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this can be done using cloud functions. That way you do not need to use your own server or create an API call for your backend, which will lead to making your work easier.

From the docs:

> Cloud Functions for Firebase lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests. Your code is stored in Google's cloud and runs in a managed environment. There's no need to manage and scale your own servers.

check this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

You can add the user to the database and then using cloud functions a database trigger will get triggered everytime a new user is added and you will get notified, or you can use the authentication to get notified when a user creates or deletes an account.

For more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

Also this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

You can make an API call to your backend wherein you can capture all the data required(In your case email_id and Name) by the backend after the user sign in. And the same data can be used by your backend to send notifications to you. You can look at FCM for sending the Push Notifications. Please let me know if I made myself clear.

Comment: Yes , thanks I'll try to do that ,but can you give me some documentation for that on how to do that if possible?

Comment: Which exact thing you want a documentation for.
1. Sending data to backend?
2. Sending Push Notifications from Backend?

Comment: When new user sign up their data and a notification on admin app , so both

Answer (score 0):

You can use service like [Logspot](https://logspot.io). No need to setup anything in your side.

1. Start tracking sign-ups on the client side with Web SDK:

   import Logspot from "@logspot/web";

   Logspot.init({ publicKey: "YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY" });

   Logspot.track({
   event: "User signed up",
   metadata: {
   email: "john@doe.com"
   }
   });
2. Install their [mobile app](https://logspot.io/mobile-app) and login.
3. Receive mobile notification on each sign up

More info in the [docs](https://developers.logspot.io).